# Problems with font mappings and Swing UI messages for Arabic and Eastern languages

Tags: java, swing, fonts, internationalization

I am testing Java Swing support for some Eastern and Arabic languages, and am getting some confusing results.

- Hindi: is Devanagari script not supported at all?
- Japanese: is 'OK' used like that?
- Why are in some languages the Swing messages not translated?
- Thai: why do the message dialog text and menu items fail to render, but not the text in JLabel and JButton?

Test code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Latin, Cyrillic & Greek writing systems not part of this test
    // AWT/Swing statically initializes some messages (e.g. 'OK', 'Cancel') -> can only test one locale at a time
    testSwing("zh", "CN", /* Simplified Chinese */ "简体中文");
    //    testSwing("zh", "TW", /* Traditional Chinese */ "繁體中文");
    //    testSwing("ja", "JP", /* Japanese */ "日本人");
    //    testSwing("ko", "KR", /* Korean */ "한국어");
    //    testSwing("hi", "IN", /* Hindi */ "हिन्दी");
    //    testSwing("th", "TH", /* Thai */ "ไทย");
    //    testSwing("ar", "EG", /* Arabic */ "اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ");
    //    testSwing("iw", "IL", /* Hebrew */ "עִבְרִית");
  }

  private static void testSwing(String language, String countryCode, String text) throws Exception {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language, countryCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, text);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JMenu menu = new JMenu(text);
    menu.add(new JMenuItem(text));
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(menu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(locale.toString()));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(text));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(text));
    frame.setSize(300, 125);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Results (AdoptOpenJDK 1.8.0_265 on Windows 10, but seems similar on Java 11 and 15):

[image]

Installed languages on my Windows 10 system:

[image]

Comment: You need to use a font that supports the language you want to use.  Use the [Font Selector](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/font-selector) to see which fonts on your system support each particular language.  You can then create a Map of language, font to support as many languages as you can.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm using [logical fonts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) (`Serif`, `SansSerif`, `Monospaced`, `Dialog`, and `DialogInput`). *Typically, each logical font name maps to several physical fonts in order to cover a large range of characters.*

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers can be found here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html

### User interface translation

Only: zh_CN, zh_TW, en, fr, de, it, ja, ko, pt_BR, es, sv

See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html#translation

[image]

### Supported Writing Systems

Specification says: *On Windows Vista, 7, and 8, when running on a Windows system with UI Language set to a language using that writing system.*

[image]